# Eclipse can't find index libraries of GCC or G++

Tags: eclipse, gcc, g++, eclipse-cdt

The instalation of CDT Tools on Eclipse can't find on index libraries of GCC or G++, but the file is running. Ex:

include stdio.h (The comment doesn't accept <> and #) The are a yellow line description: Unresolved inclusion. If I try to acess the library, just can't open because is not found.

Comment: It would help to change the language of messages gcc LC_MESSAGES=C gcc

Comment: you can try to install g++
http://youtu.be/wl75o1Yc218
sometimes it happen based on compiler issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with the HelloWorld example. "namespace Std" and "cout" gave a "not resolved" error. I fixed this by simply restarting eclipse. Seems it does not recognize all include paths after a fresh installation / project creation.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get rid of the unresolved inclusion error, under the project properties C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols, includes tab add a new a directory and choose /usr/include/c++/4.6.1

Now I don't have the unresolved warning but have all the Symbol could not resolved
Ex:

```
#include <iostream>                //
#include <stack>                   //these 3 lines are ok
using namespace std;               //

list<int> newList;                 //get Symbol 'list' could not be resolved
cout<<"message"<<endl;             //the same for 'cout' and 'endl'
```

It can build and debug just fine, but what is the point of having and IDE if it won't give you any help while coding

Answer (score 2):

Try restart eclipse, clean all, and recompile every target.

Answer (score 0):

This one is correct:

```
#include <iostream>                //
#include <list>                   //these 3 lines are ok
using namespace std;               //

int main()
{
list<int> newList;                 //get Symbol 'list' could not be resolved
cout<<"message"<<endl;             //the same for 'cout' and 'endl'
}
```

There is no "list" header and no main() in your code.